# No CMakeLists.txt in ROS Fuerte install

Tags: ros, installation, cmake, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm in the process of installing ROS on my iMac running Mountain Lion, and I'm having issues with cmake.

When I run this:
`cmake .. -DMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/fuerte -DSETUPTOOLS_DEB_LAYOUT=OFF`

I get this: `CMake Error: The source directory "/Users/NickSweet/ros-underlay" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.`

Everything went fine with `rosinstall`, except it wasn't able to get actionlib – but I doubt that's the issue. Any idea why I don't have a CMakeLists.txt in my ~/ros-underlay? Here's what I've got, in case anything else is missing:

```
> drwxr-xr-x   2 NickSweet  staff   68 12 Nov 00:08 build 
> drwxr-xr-x  19 NickSweet  staff  646 12 Nov 00:06 catkin 
> drwxr-xr-x  14 NickSweet  staff  476 12 Nov 00:06 common_msgs
> drwxr-xr-x  13 NickSweet  staff  442 12 Nov 00:06 gencpp  
> drwxr-xr-x  14 NickSweet  staff  476 12 Nov 00:06 genlisp 
> drwxr-xr-x  15 NickSweet  staff  510 12 Nov 00:06 genmsg
> drwxr-xr-x  17 NickSweet  staff  578 12 Nov 00:07 genpy
> drwxr-xr-x  15 NickSweet  staff  510 12 Nov 00:07 ros
> drwxr-xr-x  14 NickSweet  staff  476 12 Nov 00:07 ros_comm 
> drwxr-xr-x   9 NickSweet  staff  306 12 Nov 00:07 ros_tutorials 
> drwxr-xr-x  18 NickSweet  staff  612 12 Nov 00:07 roscpp_core
> drwxr-xr-x  17 NickSweet  staff  578 12 Nov 00:07 rospack 
> drwxr-xr-x  12 NickSweet  staff  408 12 Nov 00:07 rx
> drwxr-xr-x  10 NickSweet  staff  340 12 Nov 00:07 std_msgs
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48030/no-cmakelists.txt-in-ros-fuerte-install/) by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 539 on 2012-11-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-11**:
What was the rosinstall command you were using? Did you add the `--catkin` parameter? It will create a top-level CMakeLists.

**Comment by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on 2012-11-12**:
I used this:

rosinstall --catkin ~/ros-underlay http://ros.org/rosinstalls/fuerte-ros-full.rosinstall

Does that mean there's an issue with catkin, then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the problem!

ActionLib is actually hosted at https://github.com/ros-gbp/actionlib-release and no longer at it://github.com/wg-debs/actionlib-release.git – when it didn't install properly, gitinstall simply wouldn't create the CMakeLists.txt file.

The fix is to install ActionLib manually. Go into ~/ros-underlay and use

```
git clone --recursive git://github.com/ros-gbp/actionlib-release.git /Users/YOURUSERNAME/ros-underlay/actionlib
```

Then run

```
rosinstall --catkin ~/ros-underlay http://ros.org/rosinstalls/fuerte-ros-full.rosinstall
```

And hit skip when the install asks whether you want to replace actionlib. Problem solved!

---

Originally posted by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) with karma: 539 on 2012-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0